# Graph Bipartition - Normalized cuts

Tags: graph-theory

Can anyone explain me how to do the cut in a graph in the Normalized cuts algorithm descriped here: http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~bai/ECS231/returnsfinal/WangH.pdf (page 3 bottom)?

I have an image, a graph, solved eigenvalue problem, the eigenvector of the 2nd smallest eigenvalue. But I don't know how to cut the graph.

Comment: Your eigenvector has one component for each vertex in the graph. If that component is positive, then the vertex belongs to cluster 1. Otherwise, the vertex belongs to cluster 2.

Comment: Btw, the link doesn't work.